# Time to live field receiver end operation

Tags: routing

Assume I have network as follows (R1, R2, and R3 are routers):

```
LAN A -> R1 -> R2 -> R3 -> LAN B
```

Now, if LAN A generates frame for LAN B, then I am looking how many times TTL will be decremented?

LAN  A will look till DLL, then R1, R2, and R3 will decrement TTL by one each. So, net TTL is decremented by three. Is it possible that the receiver also decrements TTL? If yes, then why so?

P.S:- I have checked some online sources, and everyone says that TTL is decremented by routers only, and not by a destination host.

Comment: Why should the destination decrement TTL? The destination would receive a packet but then decide to drop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practice, a host probably doesn't decrement the TTL, but what an actual host or OS does is off-topic here.

According to [*RFC 791, Internet Protocol*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791), the IPv4 module in the host network stack should decrement the TTL, too, as it processes the IPv4 header. This is to protect upper-layer protocols from old data:

> Time to Live:  8 bits
>
> This field indicates the maximum time the datagram is allowed to
> remain in the internet system.  If this field contains the value zero,
> then the datagram must be destroyed.  This field is modified in
> internet header processing.  The time is measured in units of seconds,
> but **since every module that processes a datagram must decrease the
> TTL by at least one** even if it process the datagram in less than a
> second, the TTL must be thought of only as an upper bound on the time
> a datagram may exist.  The intention is to cause undeliverable
> datagrams to be discarded, and to bound the maximum datagram lifetime.

-and-

> Time to Live
>
> The time to live is set by the sender to the maximum time the datagram
> is allowed to be in the internet system.  If the datagram is in the
> internet system longer than the time to live, then the datagram must
> be destroyed.
>
> This field must be decreased at each point that the internet header is
> processed to reflect the time spent processing the datagram. Even if
> no local information is available on the time actually spent, the
> field must be decremented by 1.  The time is measured in units of
> seconds (i.e. the value 1 means one second).  Thus, the maximum time
> to live is 255 seconds or 4.25 minutes.  Since every module that
> processes a datagram must decrease the TTL by at least one even if it
> process the datagram in less than a second, the TTL must be thought of
> only as an upper bound on the time a datagram may exist.  The
> intention is to cause undeliverable datagrams to be discarded, and to
> bound the maximum datagram lifetime.
>
> Some higher level reliable connection protocols are based on
> assumptions that old duplicate datagrams will not arrive after a
> certain time elapses.  The TTL is a way for such protocols to have an
> assurance that their assumption is met.

This leads to some confusion. Certainly, if a host is configured to forward IPv4 packets to other hosts on other networks, including VMs on an internal, virtual network, it should decrement the TTL, but that doesn't always seem to happen in real life.

For IPv6, the wording is more specific, telling you that a node that forwards a packet must decrement the Hop Limit field. Instead of a TTL field, IPv6 uses a Hop Limit field. The IPv6 Hop Limit field is really the same thing as the IPv4 TTL field.

[*RFC 2460, Internet Protocol, Version 6 (IPv6) Specification*](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2460.txt):

> Hop Limit
>
> 8-bit unsigned integer.  Decremented by 1 by each node that forwards
> the packet. The packet is discarded if Hop Limit is decremented to
> zero.

The IPv6 RFC seems to say that IPv4 hosts are required to enforce the TTL, which doesn't seem to really happen:

> 8.2 Maximum Packet Lifetime
>
> Unlike IPv4, IPv6 nodes are not required to enforce maximum packet
> lifetime.  That is the reason the IPv4 "Time to Live" field was
> renamed "Hop Limit" in IPv6.  In practice, very few, if any, IPv4
> implementations conform to the requirement that they limit packet
> lifetime, so this is not a change in practice.  Any upper-layer
> protocol that relies on the internet layer (whether IPv4 or IPv6) to
> limit packet lifetime ought to be upgraded to provide its own
> mechanisms for detecting and discarding obsolete packets.

Comment: Is it possible that destination host decrements and  checks the TTL value before accepting ?I came across such a figure somewhere.I will post that as a separate post

Comment: That's what the RFCs say it is supposed to do, but in practice, most OSes simply do not do that. Unfortunately, questions about what hosts or OSes do are off-topic here.